# Changing theme using GetX

Tags: flutter, flutter-get

I want to change the theme to `redTheme` only when I'm on a specific route. For that purpose, I've used `routingCallback` like

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'App',
      theme: defaultTheme(context),
      initialRoute: AppPages.INITIAL,
      getPages: AppPages.routes,
      routingCallback: (routing) => _routingCallback(context, routing),
    );
  }

  _routingCallback(BuildContext context, Routing routing) {
    if (routing.current == Routes.PURSUE_MODE) {
      _changeThemeIfNeeded(redTheme(context));
    } else {
      _changeThemeIfNeeded(defaultTheme(context));
    }
  }

  void _changeThemeIfNeeded(ThemeData theme) {
    Get.changeTheme(theme);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it's causing

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════ setState() or
> markNeedsBuild() called during build. The relevant error-causing
> widget was:    Directionality
> file:///Users/jakub/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/get_navigation-3.12.0/lib/src/root/root_widget.dart:235:22
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Because of that, I've wrapped theme changing in try-catch block, so I'm not getting exception at the start

```
  void _changeThemeIfNeeded(ThemeData theme) {
    try {
      if (Get.theme != theme) {
        Get.changeTheme(theme);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Not ready e = $e');
    }
  }
```

But I believe there is more elegant approach to this problem using `Get` framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with GetX. However, in order to avoid `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.` error, you can use [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html), in your case, like this:

```
routingCallback: (routing) => WidgetsBinding.instance
      .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _routingCallback(context, routing))
```